Trouble getting Nav2 Getting Started example to run
The short-ish explanation:
Attempting to run the Nav2 Turtlebot 4 sim as described here. Ubuntu 24.04, ROS 2 jazzy, Docker image osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop-full. I end up with a running Gazebo sim with a Turtlebot in a warehouse, but none of the Nav2 stuff running and RViz is frozen. At the console, everything looks like it's starting-up nicely, but we eventually get to [ERROR] [component_container_isolated-10]: process has died [pid 2578, exit code -4, cmd '/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/rclcpp_components/component_container_isolated --ros-args --log-level info --ros-args -r __node:=nav2_container --params-file /tmp/launch_params_vt9mdti0 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_3lq_8574 -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static']. 
Some details:
I'm using the following to start the sim in a Docker container based on osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop-full:
docker run -it --net=host --privileged --volume="${XAUTHORITY}:/root/.Xauthority" --env="DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" -v="/tmp/.gazebo/:/root/.gazebo/" -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw --shm-size=1000mb osrf/ros:jazzy-desktop-full
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install ros-jazzy-navigation2 -y
apt install ros-jazzy-nav2-bringup -y
apt install ros-jazzy-nav2-minimal-tb* -y
source /opt/ros/<ros2-distro>/setup.bash
ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb4_simulation_launch.py headless:=False

Further experiments:
I decided to try to isolate which part of the launch chain was going belly-up, by launching just the Nav2 stuff with ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py. This appears to start-up nicely but eventually gets
[ERROR] [controller_server-1]: process has died [pid 2529, exit code -4, cmd '/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/nav2_controller/controller_server --ros-args --log-level info --ros-args -p use_sim_time:=False --params-file /tmp/launch_params_j3qiyfo_ -r /tf:=tf -r /tf_static:=tf_static -r cmd_vel:=cmd_vel_nav'].
Modified navigation_launch.py so that we kick-off controller_server under gdb,
[INFO] [1735521315.236052769] [controller_server]: Created progress_checker : progress_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker
[INFO] [1735521315.236860465] [controller_server]: Controller Server has progress_checker  progress checkers available.
[INFO] [1735521315.255655279] [controller_server]: Created goal checker : general_goal_checker of type nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker
[INFO] [1735521315.256179225] [controller_server]: Controller Server has general_goal_checker  goal checkers available.
[INFO] [1735521315.281767686] [controller_server]: Created controller : FollowPath of type nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController
[INFO] [1735521315.284653177] [controller_server]: Controller period is equal to model dt. Control sequence shifting is ON
[INFO] [1735521315.299918666] [controller_server]: ConstraintCritic instantiated with 1 power and 4.000000 weight.

Thread 1 "controller_serv" received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007fffef45da59 in mppi::critics::ConstraintCritic::initialize() ()
   from /opt/overlay_ws/install/nav2_mppi_controller/lib/libmppi_critics.so

the backtrace is
#0  0x00007fffefa83a26 in mppi::critics::ConstraintCritic::initialize() () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libmppi_critics.so
#1  0x00007ffff049c243 in mppi::CriticManager::loadCritics() () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libmppi_controller.so
#2  0x00007ffff049df9d in mppi::CriticManager::on_configure(std::weak_ptr<rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS>, mppi::ParametersHandler*) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libmppi_controller.so
#3  0x00007ffff047d522 in mppi::Optimizer::initialize(std::weak_ptr<rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS>, mppi::ParametersHandler*) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libmppi_controller.so
#4  0x00007ffff0458fca in nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController::configure(std::weak_ptr<rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode> const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::Buffer>, std::shared_ptr<nav2_costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS>) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libmppi_controller.so
#5  0x00007ffff7bfcdc7 in nav2_controller::ControllerServer::on_configure(rclcpp_lifecycle::State const&) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/libcontroller_server_core.so
#6  0x00007ffff7ccab9f in rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::LifecycleNodeInterfaceImpl::execute_callback(unsigned int, rclcpp_lifecycle::State const&) const () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp_lifecycle.so
#7  0x00007ffff7ccaf8d in rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::LifecycleNodeInterfaceImpl::change_state(unsigned char, rclcpp_lifecycle::node_interfaces::LifecycleNodeInterface::CallbackReturn&) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp_lifecycle.so
#8  0x00007ffff7ccb965 in rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::LifecycleNodeInterfaceImpl::on_change_state(std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_s>, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Request_<std::allocator<void> > >, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Response_<std::allocator<void> > >) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp_lifecycle.so
#9  0x00007ffff7ccc7bc in std::_Function_handler<void (std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_s>, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Request_<std::allocator<void> > >, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Response_<std::allocator<void> > >), std::_Bind<void (rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::LifecycleNodeInterfaceImpl::*(rclcpp_lifecycle::LifecycleNode::LifecycleNodeInterfaceImpl*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>))(std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_s>, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Request_<std::allocator<void> > >, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Response_<std::allocator<void> > >)> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, std::shared_ptr<rmw_request_id_s>&&, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Request_<std::allocator<void> > >&&, std::shared_ptr<lifecycle_msgs::srv::ChangeState_Response_<std::allocator<void> > >&&) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp_lifecycle.so
#10 0x00007ffff7cd2522 in ?? () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp_lifecycle.so
#11 0x00007ffff7ebc22a in ?? () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp.so
#12 0x00007ffff7de5d64 in rclcpp::Executor::execute_service(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::ServiceBase>) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp.so
#13 0x00007ffff7de9c3a in rclcpp::Executor::execute_any_executable(rclcpp::AnyExecutable&) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp.so
#14 0x00007ffff7dfb3b4 in rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor::spin() () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp.so
#15 0x00007ffff7df2339 in rclcpp::spin(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface>) () from /opt/ros/jazzy/lib/librclcpp.so
#16 0x0000555555556395 in main ()

Dunno if the backtrace is useful without a -gbuild, but could do so if that would help.
Any advice is greatly appreciated.
P.S. Also tried building from source in a dev container, with the same result (controller_server bites the dust):
export ROS_DISTRO=rolling
git clone https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2.git --branch main
docker build --tag navigation2:$ROS_DISTRO \
  --build-arg FROM_IMAGE=ros:$ROS_DISTRO \
  --build-arg OVERLAY_MIXINS="release ccache lld" \
  --cache-from ghcr.io/ros-navigation/navigation2:main \
  ./navigation2


Update: switched controller_server.FollowPath.plugin to "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner", and the simulation starts and runs. Given that the initial error is SIGILL, I'm guessing at a compilation flag in nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController that my system doesn't like.
I'll keep poking at it.
